# How to configure React proxy?

Tags: reactjs

I am making the following call:

```
private api(url: string, args: any): Promise<any> {
    Object.assign(args, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    return (
        fetch(url, args)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) return Promise.reject(response);
                return ((args.method !== 'DELETE') ? response.json() : '')
            })
    )
};
```

I have the following line in my package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

I get the following response:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/authenticate 404 (Not Found)
```

I know the proxy isn't working, because if I change the API function above to read:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080" + url, args)
```

it works correctly.

Am I missing a step in setting up my proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is on localhost only you don't need a proxy.

A proxy is used for CORS when a url is not available internally, webpack uses the the proxy to get the data.

Also if you set the proxy to `http://localhost:8080`

and you want to access `http://localhost:8080/authenticate`

the fetch api should make a call to `/authenticate` and not `http://localhost:8080/authenticate`

because webpack will essentially proxy all the missing endpoints to the proxy address provided!

> Also please note proxy is a workaround not a solution

Comment: The server and app are on different ports. So I think it needs a proxy. Is this correct?

Comment: but the origin is same (both are on localhost) so proxy won't be required. Proxy is required for requests made between two different origins
if you make request to an external api and get a cors error then you should use proxy